# Monochromator crystal

Tags: solid-state-physics, conservation-laws, crystals, braggs-law

A monochromator crystal is often used to select a specific energy value in a polychromatic beam of X-rays or neutrons.

It exploits Bragg's law that (in the von Laue formulation) states that a crystal diffracts a beam with wavevector $\vec{k}$ into a direction $\vec{k'}$ (the wavevector $\vec{k'}$ has same modulus as $\vec{k}$) iff $$\vec{k'}-\vec{k}=\vec{G}.$$ $\vec{G}$ is here a vector of the reciprocal lattice of the crystal.

Let's suppose we use a polychromatic source (of neutrons, for example), so that the modulus of the wavevectors is not fixed. A monochromator, to select a single energy (or wavevector modulus), operates by fixing the directrion of the incoming particles ($\vec{k}$) and outgoing particles ($\vec{k'}$).

But why does the equation $\vec{k'}-\vec{k}=\vec{G}$ implies that a single energy is selected in this way?

Comment: What happens when you shine white light on a diffraction grating?

Answer (score 1):

First, energy is a function of momentum
$$\epsilon(\vec{k})=\frac{\hbar^2|\vec{k}|^2}{2m}$$
Now I understand that your question is how do we know there is no more than one different $\vec{k}$ diffracting from the original beam with same direction but different absolute values (and hence energies).

The short answer is that this is because the incident beam is collimated in the sense that it has a definite direction (all momenta are collinear, although have different magnitudes).

The longer answer is as follows. Let's for a moment assume this is indeed the case. Lets say we have two momenta $\vec{k_1}$ and $\vec{k_2}$ such that their direction match, but absolute values differ. Well, if this is true the we should be able to revert the time evolution and see where these momenta came from (all laws of physics are time-reversible. Except the 2nd law of thermodynamics which is irrelevant here). Denote with $\vec{k_1^{in}}$ and $\vec{k_2^{in}}$ the pre-scattering values for $\vec{k_1}$ and $\vec{k_2}$ respectively. Then
$$\vec{k_1^{in}}=\vec{k_1}+\vec{G}\,\,\mathrm{and}\,\,\vec{k_2^{in}}=\vec{k_2}+\vec{G'}$$
Here $\vec{G}$ and $\vec{G'}$ are some lattice reciprocal vertices. Now since the incident neutron beam was directionally collimated, $\vec{k_1^{in}}$ and $\vec{k_2^{in}}$ have to be collinear just as $\vec{k_1}$ and $\vec{k_2}$. But this is in general not possible, unless you are not in some accidental special configuration (such as when your incident beam is falling normal to the crystal surface). You can easily check this by checking that the vector product $\vec{k_1^{in}} \times \vec{k_2^{in}} \neq 0$ when $\vec{k_1} \times \vec{k_2} = 0$:
$$\vec{k_1^{in}} \times \vec{k_2^{in}} = \vec{k_1} \times \vec{G'}+\vec{G}\times\vec{k_2}+\vec{G}\times \vec{G'} \neq 0\,\mathrm{(generally \, speaking)}$$
In principle you can imagine some accidental coincidence when this sum turns to be zero, but just like any coincidence, you should be able to get rid of it by tweaking of your geometry.

Comment: I think that what you said to be "generally speaking"  non-zero is instead always zero if the absolute value of the collinear $\vec{k}_1^{in}$ and $\vec{k}_2^{in}$ are multiple of each other by a rational factor, which turns out to be also the factor that relates $\vec{G}$ and $\vec{G'}$. So I believe it's not possible to get rid of the diffraction of $\vec{k}_2^{in}$ by geometry, because this happens for any incoming direction.

Comment: You are right. And this I believe is what experiments have to take care of. In the case of X-rays I can only guess that they typically don't have such broad multi-octave bandwidths. For neutrons they probably pre-filter the beams with some short-/long-pass absorber filters before Bragg monochromators. Sorry can't tell much: I am no expert in scattering spectroscopy.